SwiftUI accessibility voice over navigation bar
I want voice over to focus on navigation bar back button. Is there any other way than adding custom toolbar with back button and setting focus to true on onAppear?
If not then adding custom back button is good practice or we should leave it on OS to read first element of the content body?

You can apply accessibilitySortPriority(_:) inside your view body with the highest value used in current hierarchy. Make sure that you're applying the modifier after you added navigationTitle.
